# How to constrain a variable to be positive in emacs-lisp?

Tags: variables, emacs, numbers

I have a customizable variable `timer-granularity` used to increase/decrease the period of a timer each time the user calls something like `(timer-faster)` or `(timer-slower)`.  However, if the user sets `timer-granularity` to a negative number, then calling `(timer-slower)` will actually make the timer faster!

I'd like to constrain the value of this variable so that it is an error to try to set it to anything less than some threshold e.g.

```
(setq timer-granularity 0.3)  ;; okay
(setq timer-granularity -1)  ;; error!
```

Is this behaviour achievable?

Comment: A user can do `(setq timer-granularity "hello")` or any other non-sensical thing, since variables have no type.  The way Elisp packages deals with it normally is to check the values they receive when they use them (e.g. in timer-faster/slower).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `setq` anything to anything (whether sensible or not), but you can certainly add validation to the `customize` interface.  e.g.:

```el
(define-widget 'integer-positive 'integer
  "Value must be a positive integer."
  :validate (lambda (widget)
              (let ((value (widget-value widget)))
                (when (or (not (integerp value)) (<= value 0))
                  (widget-put widget :error "Must be a positive integer")
                  widget))))

(defcustom foo 1 "Positive int"
  :type 'integer-positive)
```

You could add error handling to `timer-faster` and `timer-slower` -- but in this case I think I would simply trust that the user knows what they're doing if they're setting values in elisp.

---

For completeness: Emacs 26.1 did introduce `add-variable-watcher` which could be used to catch an 'invalid' `setq`, but I honestly don't think it's reasonable to use that for such a trivial purpose.  The `customize` UI is the correct place to be asserting such things.

Comment: Thanks.  I had been thinking in terms of overloading `operator=` on the "class" for `timer-granularity` was.  In this case it is indeed rather trivial, but I am also trying to get a sense of what the language can do.  I will look at add-variable-watcher.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @phils's answer - you can do the same directly, without defining a new `:type`:

```el
(defcustom foo 42
  "Foo..."
  :type '(restricted-sexp
          :match-alternatives ((lambda (x) (and (natnump x)  (not (zerop x)))))))
```